# How to translate header of references/bibliography section?

Tags: r, bookdown

Bookdown offers some options for internationalization of the HTML output, i.e. translation of certain keywords (see [Bookdown Internationalization](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/internationalization.html)):

```
 language:
   ui:
     edit: Edit
     chapter_name: ''
```

Is there an option to change the header of the references/bibliography section as well, similar to the `chapter_name` variable? The header is normally called "References".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTML output you have to create that header manually (c.f. the [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/citations.html)).  So you can easily use the name you prefer, e.g.:

```
`r if (knitr::is_html_output()) '# Literatur {-}'`
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the headline for references inside a chapter or section you can alter the skeleton.R file.